# Unable to click on element using xpath - TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to click a checkbox inside div for the below css selector:

```
#sheet1 > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > div > div.GMPageOne > table > tbody > tr.GMDataRow.GMClassFocused > td.GMClassFocusedCell.GMWrap0.GMAlignCenter.GMBool0.GMCell.IBSheetFont0.GMEmpty.HideCol0C2
```

I tried different ways from google search but none worked.

```js
const example = await page.$x('//*[@id="sheet1"]/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]',{waitUntil: 'networkidle0',});
  delay(1000);
  await example[0].click();
```

This is giving an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
>       at C:\Apps\headless\node_modules\project\esi.js:60:20
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like invalid syntax.
Try this:

```
await page.waitForXPath('//*[@id="sheet1"]/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]', 5000);
const [example] = await page.$x('//*[@id="sheet1"]/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]');
if(example) await example.click();
```

Comment: Thanks @ Yevhen. It worked. Using Selenium so far. Thought of trying puppeteer so got a bit stuck as a newbie.